# Oracle database 12c : ORACLE JSON QUERY SEARCH

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

Creating two types of table to store JSON values (BLOB and NCLOB) and my aim to search the required values from JSON table;

Code Snippet 1: Creating table with one column as NCLOB.

```
create table departments_json_nclob (
  department_id   integer not null primary key,
  department_data NCLOB not null
);
```

Simple insert with multibyte character (that is value : `məharaːʂʈrə`):

```
insert into departments_json_nclob 
  values ( 200,'{"department_list":[{"Deptname":"DEPT-A", "value" : "məharaːʂʈrə"}]}');
```

Code Snippet 2: Now, I have created one other table with BLOB datatype:

```
create table departments_json (
  department_id   integer not null primary key,
  department_data blob not null
);
```

Added constraint to allow only JSON

```
alter table departments_json
  add constraint dept_data_json 
  check ( department_data is JSON FORMAT JSON STRICT );
```

Insert normal JSON

```
insert into departments_json 
  values ( 100, utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('{"department_list":[{"Deptname":"DEPT-A", "value" : "məharaːʂʈrə"}]}'));
```

Insertion Verified from below query:

```
SELECT json_value(department_data format json, '$.department_list.value'  ) 
FROM departments_json JS 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=100;
```

output is: `məharaːʂʈrə`

Now, I will have one more insertion in same table i.e. 'departments_json' but this time I will take required insertion value from NCLOB table `departments_json_nclob`:

```
declare

    i nclob;

begin

    select department_data into i from departments_json_nclob where department_id =200;

    --inserting same way as I inserted in departments_json for department_id 100 but value comes from NCLOB

    insert into departments_json 
    values ( 101, utl_raw.cast_to_raw (i));

    commit;
end;
```

Again, insertion verified with below query:

```
SELECT json_value(department_data format json, '$.department_list.value'  ) 
FROM departments_json JS 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=101;
```

output is: `məharaːʂʈrə`

Now my question is:

When I search for multibyte character, query return result of one query only that is direct insertion in BLOB table. Which is `DEPARTMENT_ID=100` - why not 101?

Below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   departments_json
WHERE JSON_value(department_data format json, '$.department_list.value') = ('məharaːʂʈrə');

SELECT *
FROM   departments_json
WHERE JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(department_data,  '$.department_list.value', 'məharaːʂʈrə')
```

below query shows which character are multibyte:

```
select c, length(c), lengthb(c) 
from ( select substr(s, level, 1) c 
       from ( select 'məharaːʂʈrə' s 
              from dual) 
       connect by level <= length(s));
```

Comment: Hi @AkshayTrivedi , for me it is like this: From this 3 last query's at the end, the first query(`...JSON_value...`) returns both rows(100 and 101), second query(`...JSON_TEXTCONTAINS...`) returns an error(`ORA-40467: JSON_TEXTCONTAINS() cannot be evaluated without a JSON-enabled context index`) so I do not understand the question ? First query returns only one row to you ?

Comment: @VBokšić , I am sorry, I did not mentioned the below index creation snippet, Index is necessary : 
                                                                                                                         
 create index deptj_ctx_ix 
  on departments_json (department_data)
    indextype is ctxsys.context     parameters ('section group  CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP  sync (on commit)');

Comment: @VBokšić, for query no 1 - (..JSON_VALUE..) Please let me know the character set from your environment :                               
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';

Comment: I have added the index. Now both query's return two rows. I am testing this on https://livesql.oracle.com. You can check the NLs parameters there under My Session >> NLS

Comment: @VBokšić, Thank you very much..it is working in [livesql.oracle](https://livesql.oracle.com). I am unable to view required NLS parameters i.e. NLS_CHARACTERSET & NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET in livesql.oracle.com. Why it is not working in SQL developer (local system setup) ? Any specific reason.. seems it is due to some characterset mismatches.

Comment: It works with like operator :                                                                          `SELECT *
FROM   departments_json
WHERE JSON_value(department_data format json, '$.department_list.value') like ('%məharaːʂʈrə%'); `

Comment: When you are in https://livesql.oracle.com/ you can see from your left side option "My Session", then when you click on that you will see option NLS. There you can see the details and compare.