# storing multibyte character in a single byte characterset environment oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Earlier we were storing `JSON` containing latest `10` conversations in an `NCLOB` column in database for caching purpose. But now we have to store all the conversations in `JSON` format and also provide search functionality. To utilize oracle's text search, we tried using `BLOB` datatype instead of `NCLOB`. However we are facing problems storing multibyte characters and searching it. Any suggestions on how to use `BLOB` datatype?

**Here's an example of what i'm attempting**

*--create table with blob column---*

```
create table departments_json (
  department_id   integer not null primary key,
  department_data blob not null
);
```

*---add JSON check constraint ---*

```
alter table departments_json
  add constraint dept_data_json 
  check ( department_data is JSON FORMAT JSON STRICT );
```

*---------------index json column for text search-------*

```
create index deptj_ctx_ix on departments_json (department_data) 
indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP sync (on commit)');
```

*--Insert Json With Multibyte Characters*

```
insert into departments_json 
  values ( 100, utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('{"department_list":[{"Deptname":"DEPT-A", "value" : "məharaːʂʈrə"}]}'));
```

**Insert fails with :** 
ORA-02290: check constraint (REGCOA_SPM.DEPT_DATA_JSON) violated

Comment: can you provide more info about `However we are facing problems storing multibyte characters and searching it.`

Comment: @moudiz I've updated my question.Thanks In advance!

Comment: `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` takes a `varchar2` as a parameter.  If you have a string that contains characters that can't be represented in the database character set, that string can't be a `varchar2` constant and can't be passed to a function that takes a `varchar2`.  I assume that in actual practice you'd have an application that is passing the data in rather than creating string constants and passing them to `cast_to_raw`.

Comment: You may be able to have the application convert the data to a binary representation and send that to the `blob` column and then tell the Text index what character set the data is actually encoded using.  But I'm not completely sure that's going to be possible with characters that can't be represented in the database character set.  Any chance that you could update the database character set to Unicode?

Comment: @JustinCave There are several of our clients on single byte env and it is not possible currently to convert their database character set. Also, can you please enlighten more on text index with character set encoding. How is it performed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909775/oracle-database-12c-oracle-json-query-search